# No picture gitlab

Tags: image, git, gitlab

I finally managed to install gitlab, by cons I do not have pictures: [image: No pictures]

Comment: That actually looks like a missing font. Perhaps GitLab uses an icon font pack that isn't installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 0):

Profile pictures can be changed directly in user profile http://demo.gitlab.com/profile